# How do I get Ambethia Recaptcha to work with simple_form .error_notification?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha, simple-form

I love the new .error_notification feature in simple_form, but I have no idea how to include my recaptcha in it.  The code I have looks like:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url =>      registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
    <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
    <%= recaptcha_tags %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I imagine I need to somehow tell simple_form something more about the recaptcha but I can't find much information about .error_notification.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

In controller:

```
unless verify_recaptcha
   @captcha_error="Word verification response is incorrect"
end
```

In view:

```
<%= recaptcha_tags %>
<span class="help-block pull-left" style="color:#a94442;"><%=@captcha_error%></span>
```

You can use variable to show your error message.